# react-native how to change functional component to class component

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need to change functional component to class component. I know how to do this but if I want to pass props how would I do it?

Functional component

```
const FunctionalComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <View>
    <View>
    <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={()=> {props.navigation.navigate('profile')}}>
      <Text>button</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>

    <ScrollView>
      <DrawerItems {...props}/>
    </ScrollView>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Class component

```
class ClassComponent extends Component = (props) => {
  render(){
  return (
    <View>
    <View>
    <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={()=> {props.navigation.navigate('profile')}}>
      <Text>button</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>

    <ScrollView>
      <DrawerItems {...props}/>
    </ScrollView>
    </View>
  )
 }
}
```

I tried this but this will throw me an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : constructor in react [source](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor).

```
class ClassComponent extends Component {      
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate('profile') }}>
            <Text>button</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
       ...
       //Other stuff
       ....
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

[source](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/props)

Comment: I thought about this too but this will throw me an error `props is not defined`

Comment: nope! u were right! I just had to put `this` in front of props.

Comment: you can use `props` by `this.props` in you have class component